# Check if path contain a string

Tags: php

I want to check if a path contain a string,

like, if path contain `plugins` then return `false`, and if path contain `themes` then return `true`.

```
D:\wamp\www\wp-content/plugins/someplugin/index.phtml // return false

D:\wamp\www\wp-content/themes/index.php // return true
```

Comment: So what would `wp-plugins` or `wp-themes` trigger?

Comment: Use strpos() for this

Comment: Also, you're mixing / and \...

Comment: What do you return if the path contains neither?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [PHP check if a string contains a string](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+check+if+a+string+contains+a+string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because [@Dave Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2344142/dave-chen) asked :

```
So what would wp-plugins or wp-themes trigger?
```

then, set an exact match :

```
$themes = "/themes/";
$file01 = "D:\wamp\www\wp-content/themes/index.php"; 
$file02 = "D:\wamp\www\wp-content/wp-themes/index.php";

$is_theme = stripos($file01, $themes ); // returns true
$is_theme = stripos($file02, $themes ); // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this suffices.

```
<?php

$pos1 = stripos('D:\wamp\www\wp-content/theme/someplugin/index.phtml', 'theme');
if ($pos1 === false) {
    echo "Not a theme";
}
else
{
    echo "It's a theme !";
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

> It's a theme !